# Delimit Fortran strings using numbers

Tags: fortran, delimiter, fortran90, fortran95

I have an input file with letters and numbers that I'd like to delimit with numbers in Fortran 90/95. The input file looks like this:

```
AAAA (spaces) 123BBBB (spaces) 4CCCC (spaces) 5DDDD (spaces) -6EEEE
```

So on and so forth. I'd like for the numbers after the spaces to be with the four letters prior to the spaces. The problem I'm running into here is that the numbers can either be one, two, three, or four digits, and can have negative signs as well. I'm not sure how to automate delimiting in Fortran to get the appropriate numbers to the correct letters.

So far, I only have written a script which essentially replicates the input file and writes it to an output file. I wanted to accomplish this first before trying delimiting as above.

ALTERNATIVELY, I can try delimiting in Python (if it's easier in Python), and call the Python delimiting script from the Fortran program.

Answer (score 2):

Fortran has the SCAN and VERIFY intrinsics that let you find the location in a string of the first (or optionally last) character that is (or is not) in a specified character set. Your example is malformed as there is no number after EEEE, but I'll ignore that for now.

The way I would handle this is to keep a position value, use INDEX to locate the next blank, which tells me how many letters are there from the current position. Then I would use VERIFY with a set ' -0123456789' to identify the next non-numeric. This tells me what the next number is. I'd use a list-directed READ from that substring to read the number. Repeat until end of string.

There are undoubtedly other ways of doing this, but calling out to another language is wholly unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work without using SCAN or VERIFY. I read each character of each string individually and converted to decimal, and inserted semicolons where necessary.